# ffserver segmentationfault

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg

This is my problem:

```
viroos@plecak-transmisyjny:~/videotesty$ sudo ffserver -d -loglevel debug
FFserver version SVN-r20420, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
built on Oct 30 2009 21:56:18 with gcc 4.4.1
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-shared --enable-nonfree
libavutil     50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0
libavcodec    52.37. 1 / 52.20. 0
libavformat   52.39. 2 / 52.31. 0
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 1. 0
libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
Segmentation fault
```

This is my /etc/ffserver.conf

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon
<Feed feed1.ffm>
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 200K
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>
<Stream output.flv>
Feed feed1.ffm
VideoBitRate 1024
VideoBufferSize 128
Format flv
VideoSize 320x240
VideoFrameRate 24
VideoQMin  3
VideoQMax  3
</Stream>
<Stream stat.html>
Format status
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>
<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you build this from source yourself? If that is the case, I would build it again and watch for any errors / warnings in the build process.

If not, even if you are doing something wrong in the configuration, a segfault should not happen.  The program should not be trying to access memory it shouldn't.  If there is an error on your part, it should print an error and exit on its own.  So you should submit a bug report if you don't see anything during the build process.

If you have the source, and want to see if you can just fix it right away. Compile with -ggdb3 and then run the executable with gdb and see where it segfaults:

```
$ gdb myexec
GNU gdb 6.8-debian
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu"...
(gdb) run
...
(gdb) bt
```

Comment: Thank You. I thought, so but when I was googling I found answer where someone suggested that could by configuration problem... This is standard package from Ubuntu 9.10. I will try compile it myself, and I will submit bug report.

Comment: Right, could be a config problem, but even if it is, it still shouldn't cause a segfault.